# Is the APPLY a RBAR-like clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As the title says, do the APPLY clause work using a RBAR logic?

Me and my colleagues use APPLY to solve particular problems and usually we get better or same performance than JOINs, even if a Subquery inside a JOIN should only be evaluated once, when the one inside APPLY is evaluated per-row.

I wanted to understand how APPLY works and why can it equals or even get better performance than JOIN.

Comment: *wrong* is highly subjective. Some people ban certain tools or techniques when others see all possible tools as being potentially useful at times and think that nothing should be off the table. In general, pick the simplest SQL that clearly articulates what you want the system to do, then measure its performance and only if its not acceptable should you start looking into alternatives.

Comment: You may want to read this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69953/ and this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69954/

Comment: Almost everything is done row-by-row under covers, that's why the halloween and similar problems exist. Nothing inherently wrong about that. APPLY operator forces a certain physical execution path, while with JOINs and other _relational_ operators the optimizer is free to choose what it considers the best. What we do with APPLY is actually very similar to a nested loop (which is often used to implement joins). And yes, when it comes to performance, row-by-row approach is still sometimes a clear winner and sometimes on par with a set-based one.